# Python не работает while True: в связке с pool.map

Tags: python, python-2.x

Добрый вечер, пытаюсь сделать чтобы программа в определенный промежуток времени проверяла ответы сервера и все это делаю в 3 потоках, проблема в том что программа сама завершается даже при включенном while True: подскажите что я делаю не так.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

settings.current_error = ""

try:

    load_sites_list("scan.txt")                                 # | LOAD SITES FROM FILE

    while True:

        seeds.seeds = []                                        # | CLEAR OLD SEEDS
        get_seeds = seeds()                                     # | GET CURRENT SEEDS

        time.sleep(settings.time_seleep)                        # | SLEEP - settings.time_seleep

        if len(get_seeds.seeds) != settings.max_scanners:       # | CHECKING HOW MUCH SCANNERS WORK

            if len(settings.sites) != settings.site_count:

                start_scan("http://" + settings.sites[settings.site_count])
                settings.site_count += 1

            else:

                print "Done ..."
                break

        else:

            settings.pool.map(scan_vendor, get_seeds.seeds)

            settings.pool.close()
            settings.pool.join()

        if settings.current_error != "":
            print "[ERROR] " + settings.current_error
```

Comment: И что пишет при завершении?

Comment: в том то и дело что не чего :D хотя программа должна еще исполняться а почему то завершается, если я сейчас удалю settings.pool.close(), settings.pool.join() то она будет работать но почему ? это ведь не правильно будет я так понимаю потоки будут висеть

Comment: полностью покажите блок try: Или уберите его, ошибку не видно из за него, скорее всего

Comment: по поводу pool.join() описано тут http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html

Comment: Ошибку я вывожу тут print "[ERROR] " + settings.current_error блок ее туда и передает

Answer (score 0):

> если я сейчас удалю settings.pool.close(), settings.pool.join() то она будет работать но почему ?

Это ошибка пытаться вызывать `pool.map()` (новую работу добавить дочерним процессам), после вызова [`pool.close()` (как документация и говорит](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.close)).

Вот полный пример кода, который к `AssertionError` ведёт:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

def get_result(arg):
    time.sleep(arg)  # do some work
    return arg

def main():
    L = [2] * 10

    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(get_result, L)
    pool.close()  # no more work
    pool.join()   # wait until child processes die

    #XXX it is an error to pass more work to the pool after pool.close()
    pool.map(get_result, L) # assertion fails

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Убедитесь, что вы видите ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  ...
    pool.map(get_result, L) # assertion fails
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    assert self._state == RUN
AssertionError
```